# How to make a value into a key?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, asynchronous

So In my data I store it as shown on the first picture:
[image]

What I wanna do is so when I fetch `const SourceData = await db.query("SELECT value,time from weather_data where weather_id = 1");`

I wanna turn it into an object that is time as key and value as value("time": value).
So the object's first value would be "2018-06-05":12 for example.
The reason I wanna do this is since I am planning on using this in a geojson so it becomes something like this (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/uber/react-map-gl/master/examples/.data/us-income.geojson) when I combine this new object with this one. [image]

If anyone have any better ideas please say, if not please tell me how I make the key into value the most efficient!

I am using Node.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using reduce assuming sourceData is an array of objects with keys time and value:

```
const result = sourceData.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr.time] = curr.value;
  return acc;
}, {})
```

Comment: The only problem with this is that it changes the format of time? It changes it from [
  { value: 11, time: 2017-07-06T22:00:00.000Z },
  { value: 12, time: 2017-07-15T22:00:00.000Z },
  { value: 13, time: 2017-07-31T22:00:00.000Z },
]
{
  'Fri Jul 07 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)': 11,
  'Sun Jul 16 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)': 12,
  'Tue Aug 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)': 13,
}

Comment: @OleDybedokken That is perfectly fine, it is changing the date object from the database into a local date time string. You can do `new Date('2017-07-15T22:00:00.000Z').toISOString()` and or even `new Date('Fri Jul 07 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)').toISOString()` and you'll see it comes out to the same value. The key thing is the JSON that you send back to your API/endpoint, you store the date as ISO/UTC and it should save fine in the database. You can't just store `2017-07-15T22:00:00.000Z`, it either has to be a string or date, and it looks like it's auto converted.